# content provider without database but saved cursors: can/need I close the queried cursor?

Tags: android

I have question regarding using a content provider without a database.

This has a list/HashMap with matrixcursors.
When a query is being done on the content provider, the requested data is being returned by saying (this is pseudocode)

```
MatrixCursor mc = someMap[2];
return mc;
```

What if the quering client closes the cursor?
I guess the cursor in someMap will also be closed, as the returned cursor is a reference to that object. Am I correct here?

Edit:

I am wondering if the getContentResolver() mechanism always takes care of a copy of the cursor, as query() is not a direct method call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have enough element to answer your question as you don't show your hashmap and how you fill it.

But in Java, if you do :

```
Cursor cursorA =  new ....
Cursor cursorB = cursorA;
Cursor cursorC = getCursorAViaAMethod();
```

cursorC, cursorB and cursorA are references (names in your code) of the same java object. 
Thus closing one, will close them all.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I thought so, but I also printed the hashcode of both objects, on the client side and in the content provider and they were different. I discussed with a colleague and he said that could be because they are in different threads. I am wondering: if the content provider is in the same thread, as the query goes via getContentResolver().query(), wouldn't this always be serialized?